For example/like/such as

Writers have always used metaphor. For example, Cicero compared the human figure to a vase.

There are some simple changes you can make for a healthier life. For example, you could take the stairs instead of the lift.

Writers have always used metaphor, like/such as Cicero compared the human figure to a vase.

There are some simple changes you can make for a healthier life, like/such as you could take the stairs instead of the lift.


Sentences 1 and 2 are taken from a dictionary. Are my sentences 3 and 4 correct with "like" or "such as"?

Not without changing the wording. For example introduces a new sentence - You (subject) could take the stairs instead of the lift.
Like and such as need to be followed by a phrase identifying the thing you are using as an example.

Writers have always used metaphor, such as Cicero's comparison of the human figure to a vase.
There are some changes you can make for a healthier life, like taking the stairs instead of the lift.


But I could easily replace the "for example" with "for instance" in sentences 1 and 2 in the OP. Am I right?

Yes, you could.
